# Linq expressions where empty string acts as wildcard

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm trying to write a search function with about 10 inputs in my criteria, all of the inputs are nullable.

What I've come up with is below however if the input is null I'd like it to act as a wildcard.

For example if **model = ""** id like the search query to act like:

```
context.products.where(product => product.location == location && product.type  == type).tolist();
```

I'm sure it can be done with a load of if statements however there must be better solution.
Any ideas?

```
 public static List<product> Search(FormCollection formCollection)
            {

     var model = formCollection["model"];
     var location = formCollection["location"];
     var type = formCollection["type"];


    var results = context.products.where(product => product.model == model && product.location == location && product.type  == type).tolist();

    return results;

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var results = context.products
    .where(product => (model == null || product.model == model)
                && (location == null || product.location == location)
                && (type == null || product.type  == type)).tolist();
```